# The complexity of the LRU cache algorithm

Tags: algorithm, caching, c++11, stl

I have in front of me a task to implement the LRU cache. And the longest operation in the system should take `O(log (n))`. As my Cache I use `std :: MAP`. I still need a second container for storing key + Creation Time - Sort by time. And when I need to update the address to the cache it should take somewhere:

- Find by key `O(log (n))`.
- Remove to an iterator `O(1)`.
- Insert a new element of the `O(log (n))`.

The oldest member must reside naturally in `container.begin()`.

I can use only STL.

List - does not suit me.

```
list.find() - O (n)
```

Priority Queue - delete items not implemented.

I think it could ideally be stored in a `std::set`;

```
std::set<pair<KEY, TIME>>;
```

**Sort `std::set`:**

```
struct compare
{
    bool operator ()(const pair<K, TIME> &a, const pair<K, TIME> &b)
    {
        return a.second < b.second;
    }
};
```

And to find a key in `std :: set` to write the function wich looks for the first element of the pair - `std::set<pair<KEY, TIME>>;`.

What do you think? Can anyone tell if this suits my specified complexity requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use **map** plus **set** to get the complexity of deleting/updating/inserting as **O(logn)**.

1. map stores **key,value** pair.
2. set should store **time,key** in this order  ( you have done opposite ). When cache is full and you want to remove a key it will be correspong to the element in set to which **it = myset.begin()** points to.

Having said that you can improve performance by using **hash + double linked list**.

Comment: Does using a hash and list improve the time complexity to O(1) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve O(1) complexity when chose proper data structures:

template<typename Key_t, typename Value_t>
class LruCache {
....
using Order_t = std::list<Key_t>;
Order_t m_order;
std::unordered_map<Key_t, std::pair<typename Order_t::iterator, Value_t>> m_container;
};

m_order is a list. You need to add some elements at the beginning or at the end of the list (O(1)).
Removing an item from a list if you have iterator to it: m_order.erase(it) - O(1).
Removing Recently Used Key from a list: pop_front/pop_back: O(1).

When you need to find a key, use hash_map - find - (O(1) on average).
When you found a key, you have a value, which is the real value and in addition an iterator to proper item in the list.

The whole complexity can be O(1), then.

Comment: "The whole complexity can be O(1), then." this simply cannot be. Please provide a proof.